# How to append list index Python

Tags: python, csv, indexing, append, row

Please help, I can't find it.

Why can I append `row` but not `row[2]`? It crashes. I'm using Python 3.4.3.

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", encoding="UTF8") as csvfile:
    read = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=";")

    original = []

    for row in read:
        original.append(row[2])


csvfile.close()
print(original)
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `row` contains fewer than three elements?

Comment: Kevin is probably on to something. It's hard to debug a crash without seeing the error message from the crash.

Comment: It's 6 elements & no errors, just crash.

Comment: How can you tell it crashed? :)

Comment: PyCharm is not responding at all after running this, it just crashes.

Comment: what is the error traceback from the *crash*?

Comment: Btw, just a note. There is no need in closing the file explicitly - it would be closed by the context manager - remove the `csvfile.close()` line.

Comment: There is no errors, it takes about 60% of CPU after running this.

Comment: How big is your csv file?

Comment: 138 kB 1400 lines and 6 columns.

Comment: I can print row[2] without problems in a few ms.

Comment: Does it still go wrong if you comment out the print statement? You are trying to print the whole thing in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a frustrating debugging experience.

One possibility is that there's a last line in the file that has only one item which is causing the issue.

A quick way to look at the situation (depending how long your file is) might be to throw in a print and see what's going on, line by line:

```
for row in read:
    try:
        original.append(row[2])
    except:
        print(row)
```

If you run with this, you may be able to see what happens just before the *crash*.

You may want to be a little more descriptive on what the *crash* is.  It's famously difficult to help with such a vague description.  A little more effort will help people to help you more effectively.

Comment: Thanks. it freezes, it takes about 60% of CPU. Tried what you wrote and the problem thing is the print(original) part, the appending seems to work just fine. Maybe the list is to long? About 1400 items. But works if i append just row though.

Comment: I adjusted the code.  It should now only print when it fails.  Freezing does suggest a memory leak somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do not try and print the whole of your CSV list at the end, this can cause some IDEs to lock up for a long time.

Instead you could just print the last few entries to prove it has worked:

```
print("Rows read:", len(original)
print(original[-10:])
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. It was just too much at once ( 1408 ) Thank you! :-)